# Loading win32 dll with Universal Windows Platform (UWP) calls from Python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, windows

I want to call the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) API from Python.  I tried to do that by using ctypes to call a win32 dll containing functions which call the UWP API.

To summarize the flow of that:
Python->cytpes->dll->UWP

I am stuck on debugging that.  Here is what *does* work:

- Creating a win32 dll file and calling C functions inside of it using
  the Python ctypes module
- Building a win32 dll file containing UWP calls (using instructions [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#KAzMCwdBZT5c0Oc8.97)).
- Loading the win32 dll file from a C++ win32 application and calling functions which make UWP API calls.

Here is what *does not* work:

- UWP calls within the win32 DLL when that dll is loaded with Python ctypes; The same UWP call which worked when the same DLL was loaded and invoked from a win32 application fails when invoked from ctypes.

The Python 3.6.4 code looks like this:

```
dll = ctypes.CDLL(path_to_dll)
dll.IsKeyboardPresent.restype = ctypes.c_bool
is_keyboard_present = dll.IsKeyboardPresent()
```

The traceback after it crashes ends with this:

```
is_keyboard_present = dll.IsKeyboardPresent()  
OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error [0xe06d7363][2]
```

The source code to the dll file is this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Input;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;


extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) bool IsKeyboardPresent()
{
    bool is_present = 0;

    KeyboardCapabilities^ kbdCapabilities = ref new KeyboardCapabilities();
    is_present = (bool)kbdCapabilities->KeyboardPresent;

    return is_present;
}
```

Again, works from C++ but not from ctypes.  Commenting out this one line makes it not crash from ctypes:

```
KeyboardCapabilities^ kbdCapabilities = ref new KeyboardCapabilities();
```

The C++ snippet in the win32 App which loads the dll and invokes the contained function without error:

```
typedef int(__stdcall *ISKEYBOARDPRESENT)();

HINSTANCE hinstLib;
ISKEYBOARDPRESENT IsKeyboardPresentProc;
BOOL fFreeResult;

bool is_keyboard_present;

hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Win32Project2.dll"));
if (NULL != hinstLib) {
    IsKeyboardPresentProc = (ISKEYBOARDPRESENT)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "IsKeyboardPresent");
    if (NULL != IsKeyboardPresentProc)
    {
        is_keyboard_present = (IsKeyboardPresentProc)();
    }
    fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);

}
```

This is on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 and 32-bit Python 3.6.4

Feels like I am really close but got stuck here.  For one reason, the Windows Error code is too general to point me in any direction.  Also, when I call the DLL from Python it does not hit the debugging point which I set in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you run python.exe itself in the debugger (or attached to it after it was started)?